# JPA thinks null is 0 and generates a FK constraint fail

Tags: jpa, null, integer

JPA thinks `null` is `0` and generates a foreign key (FK) constraint fail. Therefore, I can't insert a new row that has a null value where I want to. This only happens for one attribute.

I have this in my entity.

```
@Column(name = "original_language_id", nullable = true)
private int originalLanguageId;
```

This attribute can be null, however creating a new row. It works perfectly when this attribute has a valid number (i.e. that belongs to the language table), but it doesn't work when I don't send any number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column is defined as an `int`:

```
private int originalLanguageId;
```

An `int` is never null. The default value is 0, hence that being inserted.

To make the post complete, try `Integer` as Thilo commented instead:

```
private Integer originalLanguageId;
```

This works since `Integer` is a class (boxing & unboxing of your underlying value) as opposed to the primitive type `int`.

Comment: Use `Integer` instead.

Comment: Do you know who I want to kiss right now? Well, you. Thanks :)